# git pull in windows doesn't work when the branch name had double quotes

Tags: git, git-bash

I am trying to find a workaround, in private gitlab, i noticed some user accidently typed `"` : branch is named something like `story/UI_login_feature"`.

This seems to work fine in Linux box, when i issue git pull.

Windows is not able to pull, since i get below message whatever i do.
i used, git bash to create the file manually still it is not working

```
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/story/UI_login_feature"':
Unable to create 'C:/Users/tim/git/webapp/.git/refs/remotes/origin/story/UI_login_feature".lock':
Invalid argument
```

Deleting the branch is not an option for me now since it has some other user changes.

Comment: How about creating a new branch to replace the problematic one?

Comment: As ElpieKay suggested : from your linux box (you seem to have one), create a correctly named branch from the bad name, push that new branch, and delete the badly named one. If this branch is shared : inform your coworkers to fetch/pull from the correctly named branch.

Comment: Does this help? https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-rename-local-and-remote-git-branch/

Answer (score 1):

In Windows you cannot use certain chars in a file or folder name; a double quote is one of those.

Basically the error says that you can't create `UI_login_feature"` file.

You can create at the begging a new branch from the double quoted one:

```
>git checkout -b my_new_branch story/UI_login_feature\"
```

and you can continue from here in windows.